# jquery codes not working in the loaded external html file

Tags: jquery

i am using this code to load a external html file into main `index.php` file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fld").click(function(){
        $("#collection").load($(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```

the codes gets data from this html file,
`<a class="fld" name="external.html" href="#">Folder 1</a>`
Here is the external.html file
`<a class="song" href="#" name="http://impk.co.in/sound/sound1.mp3">Song1</a>`

Now after loading that `external.html` file into `index.php` jquery functions are not working for that `external.html` file only. rest jquery functions are still working.

[This is the demo link to the website](http://impk.co.in/error/)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an event delegation problem.  When you first bind to elements with `.click`, etc., the event is bound immediately to existing elements.  If an element does not exist in the DOM, the event is not bound to it.  It does not get automatically bound if that element is added later (e.g. through Ajax).

You can delegate by binding to an element that exist (even up to `document`) and specifying a selector that should match, such as this:

```
$("#collection").on('click', '.song', function () { ...
```

Notice the second argument.

Comment: +1 Your answer appeared while I was clicking on 'Post your answer'. You beat me by half a second :)

Comment: i want to fetch data from `a#fld` not from `.song` into the `<div id="collection"`

Comment: the maain problem is that, after loading `external.html` file using `$.load()` ,the jquery functions for that `external.html` file is not working. but if i use `<?php`include('external.html'); ?>` . then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's load() function doesn't copy event binding for several reasons. It only handles the appending of the target elements to the current DOM. You'll have to rebind them, or use on().

Comment: Thanks for your all helps. the problem is now solved.[The Solved Page Is Here](http://impk.co.in/music/)